# Appending two structures

Tags: c, gcc

I'm trying to append two structures into one
Ex.

```
l1 = add(1, add(2, NULL));
l2 = add(3, add(4, NULL));
myappend(l1,l2) = add(1,add(2,add(3,add(4,NULL))))
```

I tried many other ways that I can think of... but it doesn't work... can anyone help me out?

```
struct list_node {
   struct list_node * rest;
   int first;
};

list add(int in, list l) {
   list r = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
   r->first = in;
   r->rest = l;
   return r;
}
// My attempted solution;
list myappend(list l1,list l2){
   list k = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
   k=l2;
   k=add(l1,k);
   return k;
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" -- more precisely?

Comment: "I tried many other ways that I can think of" such as?

Comment: I don't see a definition for "list". What is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess the type `list` is `struct list_node *`. If you can define a type for `list`, you can define a type for `list` with a `last` point to the last node of the list, example:

```
struct list {
    struct list_node *first;
    struct list_node *last;
}
void myappend(struct list *l1,struct list *l2){
   // check the argument here when needed.

   l1->last->rest = l2->first;
   l1->last = l2->last;
   free(l2);
}
```

If you want to keep the type `list` as `struct list_node *`, you should
1) Ensure the last node(of a list)'s `rest` is NULL.
2) Loop and find the last node of the fist list and do the merge(just link them).

You can also use recursion code:

```
list __add(struct list_node *first_node, list rest) { // split your list_add()
   first_node->rest = rest;
   return first_node
}
list add(int in, list l) {
   list r = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
   r->rest = NULL;
   r->first = in;
   return __add(r, l);
}
list myappend(list l1,list l2){
   if (l1)
       return __add(l1, myappend(l1->rest, l2));
   else
       return l2;
}
```

Comment: Note: Don't use identifiers with leading underscores. They are reserved.

Answer (score 2):

```
list myappend(list l1,list l2){ 
   list k = l1;
   while (k->rest != NULL)
   {
     k = k->rest;
   }
   k->rest = l2;
   return l1; 
}
```

Should work for you.

Comment: @user1516649 Without changing the data structure, I'm afraid, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Your solutions suffers of a number of problems.

Here you create a pointer to a `list_node` (that you call `list`)...

```
list k = malloc(sizeof(struct list_node));
```

... and then you throw that node away by overwriting that pointer with `l2`!

```
k=l2;
```

Here you pass `l1` (a `list`) instead of an `int`, as a first argument.

```
k=add(l1,k);
```